# woocommerce product excerpt description (short)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to remove **wordpress html-formatting** in woocommerce product short description. It add **p** tag everywhere. I know how to do it in wp posts and pages

> remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );

but it didn't work with woocommerce product short desc

i was trying to use this code

> remove_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'wpautop' );

Thank you anyway!

Comment: This might be of use to you in extremis - never a good idea to mess with core files but if you can't stop it any other way https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L0 is the `wp_autop()`  This was where a similar but dieefernt thing happened http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850117/wordpress-inserting-opening-p-tag-inside-of-my-shortcode/33850522#33850522

Comment: `remove_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'wpautop' , 99 );`    might be a more correct way to get there if it works:     http://ipanelthemes.com/kb/misc/wordpress/fixing-themes-custom-wpautop-priority/

Comment: This explains it better and might help - although it relates to self closing it shows how to work with the `wp_autop()` function:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-do-i-turn-off-self-closing-tags-for-markup-in-wordpress-for-html5-or-html4/116#116

Comment: Thisexplains more about removing filters which I hope might help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26836720/cant-remove-function-from-wordpress-woocommerce-hook-using-remove-action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it like this...

```
function rei_woocommerce_short_description($the_excerpt) {

    return wp_strip_all_tags($the_excerpt);
}
add_filter('woocommerce_short_description', 'rei_woocommerce_short_description',10, 1);
```

**Note:**

1. [wp_strip_all_tags](http://wpseek.com/wp_strip_all_tags/) will strip all HTML tags including script and style.
2. pass second parameter true if you want to remove break tag `<br/>` also.

```
    return wp_strip_all_tags( $the_excerpt, true );
```

Comment: thx a lot it works for me. but it strips all HTML tags) only simple text left. but i need to remove unnecessary tags that wordpress add by it's own. right now wp add everywhere **<p> tag**. MB there is another function that remove tags that i can control (choose )

Answer (score 1):

To remove a filter you have to call that from inside a function that is added to a hook. I don't 100% know why that is, but that seems to be the case. While you can call `add_action()` directly in your plugin/theme you cannot call `remove_action()`. You can see that the `wpauto` is added to the [`woocommerce_short_description`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-core-functions.php#L44) filter. So to remove it you must do something like the following:

```
function so_34700299_remote_autop(){
    remove_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description', 'wpautop' );
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'so_34700299_remove_autop' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like you remove `wpautop` in post and pages content, use the same remove filter function, but with correct hook.

```
remove_filter('woocommerce_short_description','wpautop');
```

This is all you would need. No fanciness in the functions.php, no creating of additional functions with a hook and then calling remove filter in it. Enjoy!